# Have man pages display how far I am through the file

Tags: man, less

With `less`, the `-m` flag extends the prompt to include a percentage. But how do I get man to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up setting `$LESS=M` in my `.bash_profile` file. That worked!

Comment: I think you mean `-M`. See this [stackoverflow answer for more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049350/unable-to-make-less-to-indicate-location-in-percentage)...